# How do I generate the same result in a random.randint only twice

Tags: python, string, random, file-management

I might have not explained myself clearly in the constrained space of the title, but I will try my best to explain myself here.

My code has a function that generates a random integer between 0 and the number of lines of a .txt file. Each line is a string of text. That text is then passed to a second function that turns it into some sort of a typing test. In another one, I test the characters entered by the user compared to the string he was supposed to enter. But it doesn't do that. It goes ahead and generates an entirely new string again, and compares it, obviously the user gets an abysmal error rate and very low WPM. Here is my code:

````
import time
import random
import string
import sys
import string
import sys

#from getkey import getkey

def generateTest():
    mylines = []                              
    with open ('phrases.txt', 'rt') as myfile:  # Open phrases.txt for reading the typing tests
        for line in myfile:                   # For each line of text,
            mylines.append(line)              # add that line to the list.

    # Converting lines of list to select a random phrase
    listLen = len(mylines) - 1 
    return (mylines[random.randint(0,listLen)])

def speedCalc():
    # words / time passed (assuming it is 5)
    start = time.time()
    test = input(print(generateTest()))
    end = time.time()
    timePassed = (end - start) 
    generateTestLen = len(generateTest())

    return generateTest(), timePassed, ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60

def spellCheck():
    test, timePassed, wpm = speedCalc()
    diff = 0
    correctChars = 0

    file_A = generateTest()
    file_B = test

    #read_A=open(file_A,'r').read()
    #read_B=open(file_B,'r').read()

    for char_a, char_b in zip(file_A, file_B):
        if char_a == char_b:
            correctChars = correctChars+1
    file_A_len = len(file_A)

    correctPercent = (correctChars/file_A_len)*100

    errors = file_A_len - correctChars
    errorRate = errors/timePassed

    netWPM = wpm - errorRate

    return correctPercent, errors, netWPM

correctPercent, errors, netWPM = spellCheck()
print(correctPercent)
print(errors)
print(netWPM)```
````

Comment: Only call `generateTest()` *once* somewhere and save its value in a variable, perhaps passing it around, instead of calling it again and again and of course getting a new value every time…?!

Comment: Every time you call *generateTest()* you stand a good chance of getting a different line from the file

Comment: If you really wanted `generateTest()` to produce the same answer twice, you'd seed to seed the random number generator to the same constant before the two calls, but that's just really bad code design. As was indicated already, call it just once, store the results and pass them around where needed.